# XCode IOS Beginner UIViewController Class change with button

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I am new to programming, I have been searching all night long and tyring to figure this out for a long time. Cant.... I dont want to use a navigation Controller but what I am trying to do is this.

So I have two classes in my project. Class1 and Class2. Now there is a button in Class1. If this button is pressed, I want the screen to go to Class2. The closest I got was creating a parent class but when I do that, the button remains on both classes.

```
- (IBAction)addScheduleB:(id)sender {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"View Curl" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.00];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    if (self.firstScreen.view.superview ==nil){
        if(self.firstScreen==nil) {
            self.firstScreen = [[FirstScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstScreen" bundle:nil];
        }
        [self.config1.view removeFromSuperview];
        [self.view insertSubview:self.firstScreen.view atIndex:0];
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.view cache:YES];
        [self.config1.view removeFromSuperview];
        [self.view insertSubview:self.firstScreen.view atIndex:0];
        [sender setTitle:@"Switch To DVR"];

    }
    else{
        if(self.config1 == nil){
            self.config1 = [[Config1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Config1" bundle:nil];
        }
        [self.firstScreen.view removeFromSuperview];
        [self.view insertSubview:self.config1.view atIndex:0];
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:YES];
        [self.firstScreen.view removeFromSuperview];
        [self.view insertSubview:self.config1.view atIndex:0];
        [sender setTitle:@"Switch To TV"];
    }
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

I want to remove the parent class and have just the two classes.

Is it possible to have a button inside class1 when pushed will take me to class2???

Comment: Do you want to go from one view to another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a 7 minute tutorial on YouTube [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ANDvhCWWIc0). That shows how to move from one view to another using a button without storybord so you will be able to lern the code to move from one class to another.

I hope this helps. As for being a beginner if you look around youtube you will find lots of tutorials to help you learn. :)

EDIT: this does not use a navigation controller

Comment: I am really stupid, I knew this. I havent coded in a few weeks and im a beginner. I wasted a day on this. and I also kept typing presentedViewController instead of presentViewController. 

Thank you so much. i wish I posted earlier.

I will def. search youtube now before posting.

Answer (score 0):

i hope This solution helps You
just make object from Class2 and when Button1 Pressed add Class2's object.View as subview to Class1.view

Good Luck

Comment: The poster clearly says he doesn't want to use Nav Controller (for whatever reason)

Answer (score 0):

you may pop the another view with modal flip transition:

```
[self presentViewController:Class2 animated:YES completion:^{
        // Some code on completeion
 }];
```

to dismiss the Class2 view:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    //code
}];
```

if you don't want to go out of current view controller, you may flip it this way:

```
BOOL toShowSecond = YES;
```

...

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                  duration:1.0
                   options:(toShowSecond?UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight)
                animations:^{
                    if(toShowSecond) {
                        firstView.hidden = YES;
                        secondView.hidden = NO;
                    } else {
                        firstView.hidden = NO;
                        secondView.hidden = YES;
                    }
                }
                completion:^(BOOL finished){
                    toShowSecond = !toShowSecond;
                }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like :

```
- (IBAction)flipViews {
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6f];

if ([saisieCompleteView superview])
{
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.view cache:YES];
    [saisieCompleteView removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:saisieRapideView];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:saisieCompleteView];
}
else {
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:YES];
    [saisieRapideView removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:saisieCompleteView];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:saisieRapideView];
}

[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

The both saisieCompleteView and saisieRapideView must be subview of your principal view.